# Open window if it doesn't exist and maximize if it exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to open a popup windows if it doesn't exists. In case it gets minimized, I want the same command to maximize the previously opened windows. Here is my code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function newPopup(url) {

   if(popup_name.exists){
       maximize(popup_name);
   }

   else{
       popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popup_name','height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + ',fullscreen=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes')
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I confirm a browser window is open, with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221432/how-do-i-confirm-a-browser-window-is-open-with-javascript)

Comment: I am not getting this to work with the solution you mentioned. A new window opens every time. The behaviour is not different from my code.